# Remove duplicated row in column and keep last row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1 COL2 COL3           COL4
NA   NA   Sp_canis_lupus 10
3    8    Sp_canis_lupus 10
3    8    Sp_canis_lupus 10
```

How can I remove duplicate rows in `COL3` and keep the last row ?

Here I should get :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3           COL4
3    8    Sp_canis_lupus 10
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also solve this with `aggregate`, like below:

```
aggregate(. ~ COL3, data = df, FUN = tail, 1)
```

Or another way in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(COL3) %>%
  slice(n())
```

This of course assumes that you're only after duplicates in `COL3` - otherwise you'll need to rephrase the problem (as the example doesn't seem to be particularly complex).

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(COL3) %>%
 filter(row_numer() == n() )
```

Upvote if it helps thanks!

Comment: Where is the information about the fact that I want to keep only the last row?

Comment: in ```row_number() == n()``` you keep the last row of each level of COL3. Is that what you were looking for is it not?

Comment: But I get the message ```x 'row_number' object not found```

Comment: sorry I missed the ```()``` I updated the comment now

Comment: I get the same error message ...

Comment: This will work better than Roman answer. Roman answer needs to add ```x[!duplicated(x$COL3), ]``` I think.

Comment: what version of dplyr are you using? I have dplyr_0.8.3

Comment: maybe ```dplyr::row_number()```

Comment: Somehow, this solution of using `filter(row_number()==n())` is faster with my 3m-row dataframe than the accepted solution of using `slice(n())` above. Both work fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `duplicated` to find duplicates - and then select those that are not duplicated, i.e. `x[!duplicated(x), ]`. You may need to make the statement a bit more elaborate given that you have NAs in there.